# sql query for difference of same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my database showing debit of my sales. here column type takes 0 as due amount and 1 as paid amount. I'm trying to calculate remaining due.

```
code Name   due bill date        type
--------------------------------------
113  ABC    30  9   2018-04-03    0
113  ABC    7   10  2018-04-03    0
113  ABC    20  11  2018-04-05    1
114  XYZ    25  25  2018-05-06    0
```

This is my desired table when 20 is subtracted from 37

```
code Name      due 
------------------
113 ABC        17
114 XYZ        25
```

I've used this query

```
select code, name,SUM(amount) from Debit group by code, name, type
```

what will be the correct query for above problem? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags, this is not related to [tag:c#]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can use solved by removing `[Type]` from the `GROUP BY` clause, and add a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT code,
       [name],
       SUM(CASE [Type] WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * amount) AS due
FROM Debit
GROUP BY code,
         [name];
```

Comment: "8 amount" should be "* amount"

Comment: Oops! Must have let go of SHIFT early!

Comment: It confused the hell out of me for a while.  :)  +1

Answer (score 4):

You want something like this:

```
select code, name,
       sum(case when type = 0 then due else - due end) as due
from t
where type in (0, 1)
group by code, name;
```

Comment: this work perfect for me. Thank you for your response

Comment: what if i don't want to display due having 0

Comment: your answer isn't wrong at all however second comment was more optimized for using and easy to understand to beginner

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following query

```
SELECT A.code, A.name, (CASE WHEN A.due>A.payment THEN a.due-A.payment
                        CASE WHEN A.due>0 THEN A.due ELSE 0 END) AS due FROM 
(SELECT code,name, sum(case when type = 1 then due end) due, 
                   sum(case when type = 0 then due end) payment 
FROM [table] GROUP BY code,name) A
```